# How to run video from raw folder in android?

Tags: android, android-videoview

I have tried to run a video from raw folder just following this question [How to play a local video from resources folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8391363/how-to-play-a-local-video-from-resources-folder?rq=1) 
But it did not works for me. 
My video format is .m4v. How can I run .m4v format video in android?

Comment: can u post ur video.xml??

Comment: also check this http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html

Answer (score 2):

```
VideoView videoview = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoview);
videoview.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.video));
videoview.start();
```

The `.m4v` format is not supported, here is [the official list of supported video formats](https://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html#core). You will have to convert your video to a supported format.

Comment: I tried this but did not works for me. My video format is .m4v

Answer (score 0):

```
private VideoView vd; / class variable

vd = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoview);

playVideo();
```

**playVideo() method**

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() +"/"+ R.raw.ur_videoFile_name); 
vd.setVideoURI(uri);
//MediaController mc = new MediaController(this);
//vd.setMediaController(mc);
vd.setMediaController(null);
vd.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String videoSource = "android.resource://"+getpackageName()+"/raw/"+videofile name w/o file extension;
VideoView myVideoView = (VideoView) videoView
                                .findViewById(R.id.myvideoview);
myVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(videoSource));
myVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(MyActivity.this));
myVideoView.requestFocus();
myVideoView.start();
```

This just works!

Comment: what is ths videofile name w/o file extension. can you explain it by providing an example.

Comment: my file name is "hola.3gp". I just mentioned "hola"

Comment: what is the meaning of w/o file extension.